# TPM chip problems when installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, software-installation

I am trying to migrate from Windows 10 to Ubuntu 18.04, on a Sager laptop with an RTX 2070 graphics card. However I get the following error messages when trying to use/install Ubuntu:

```
...Error communicating to TPM chip

...

...Failed to create kernel channel -22
```

My TPM chip was originally enabled in BIOS. I tried booting both with TPM enabled (also with "Clear TPM" sub-setting both enabled and disabled) and disabled, but still could not get past the Ubuntu loading screen. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: Being unable to access the TPM chip should not prevent Ubuntu from booting. The problem that is stopping you from getting past the loading screen might be the graphics card drivers, since open-source support for RTX 20xx series is still quite work-in-progress. Also, many laptops with NVidia GPUs also include the NVidia Optimus technology (i.e. the ability to choose between power-saving Intel iGPU and powerful discrete NVidia GPU), which can be implemented in multiple ways, not all of which are easy to support automatically in Linux.

Comment: As per [telcoM](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/258991/telcom), I solved my problem by selecting the second item `Ubuntu (safe graphics)` on GRUB screen.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to install Ubuntu 20 from a USB, the installation process was stuck on: "error connecting to TPM chip". I found it was probably because of the Nvidia video drivers, so I disconnected the Nvidia video card physically, and could finally finish the installation. After Ubuntu was correctly installed, I pluged-in the video card, the system started correctly, downloaded, and installed the Nvidia drivers successfully. Hope this helps